# Error Code: 1054. Unknown Column 'credits' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services

I'm getting this error when I try to run this INSERT INTO query:

```
INSERT INTO Rush (firstName, lastName, schoolYearID, credits, gpa, age, phone, email, statusID, legacy, password)
    VALUES ('Greg','Johnson', 1, 22, 2.4, 18, '1235368965', 'gjohnson@umd.edu', 1, 'NR', 'gjohns');
```

I'm don't exactly understand why I'm getting this error because this INSERT INTO query has been run successfully in the past. I've been making some changes to the other tables in my database, however I don't think that should be an issue because the credits column is not an foreign key. This database is on Amazon AWS and is running MySQL 5.6.13. Can anyone spot my error? The schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Rush (
    rushID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    schoolYearID INT NOT NULL,
    hometown VARCHAR (25),
    homestate VARCHAR (25),
    highschool VARCHAR (50),
    credits INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    gpa DECIMAL (4,3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    major VARCHAR (25),
    biography VARCHAR (500),
    onlinepf VARCHAR (100),
    profilePictureURL VARCHAR (200), -- User uploads profile picture to another site, the url will be used in an img tag
    age INT NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    statusID INT NOT NULL,
    legacy VARCHAR(6) DEFAULT 'NR',
    legacyInfo VARCHAR (50),
    password VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (rushID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Rush_schoolYearID 
        FOREIGN KEY (schoolYearID)
        REFERENCES School_Year (schoolYearID)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Rush_statusID 
        FOREIGN KEY (statusID)
        REFERENCES Rush_Status (statusID)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER Rush_Insert BEFORE INSERT ON Rush FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
     IF (NEW.firstName = '') THEN SET NEW.firstName = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.lastName = '') THEN SET NEW.lastName = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.phone = '') THEN SET NEW.phone = null; END IF;
     IF (CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.phone) != 10 OR NEW.phone NOT REGEXP '[0-9]') THEN SET NEW.phone = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.email = '') THEN SET NEW.email = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.gpa = '') THEN SET NEW.gpa = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.password = '') THEN SET NEW.password = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.credits = '') THEN SET NEW.credits = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.gpa < 2.5 AND credits < 12) THEN SET NEW.statusID = 0;
        ELSE SET NEW.statusID = 1; END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER Rush_Update BEFORE UPDATE ON Rush FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
     IF (NEW.firstName = '') THEN SET NEW.firstName = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.lastName = '') THEN SET NEW.lastName = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.phone = '') THEN SET NEW.phone = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.email = '') THEN SET NEW.email = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.gpa = '') THEN SET NEW.gpa = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.password = '') THEN SET NEW.password = null; END IF;
     IF (NEW.credits = '') THEN SET NEW.credits = null; END IF;
     IF (OLD.statusID = 0 AND NEW.gpa >= 2.5 AND credits >= 12) THEN SET NEW.statusID = 1; END IF;
     IF (NEW.gpa < 2.5 AND NEW.credits < 12 AND statusID < 2) THEN SET NEW.statusID = 0; END IF;
     IF (NEW.gpa > 4) THEN SET NEW.gpa = null; END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess its in the trigger which is throwing the error

```
IF (NEW.gpa < 2.5 AND credits < 12) THEN SET NEW.statusID = 0;
```

should be

```
IF (NEW.gpa < 2.5 AND NEW.credits < 12) THEN SET NEW.statusID = 0;
```